# Redirect IP Address to Domain Name; Domain name from Godaddy and server from aws amazon

Tags: model-view-controller, iis-7

I am attempting to redirect the IP address of my domain to the domain name and am running into trouble. The IP address does not redirect to the domain name listed in the redirect statement below.

The IP Address is http://54.163.166.178/

I've setup the following rule in my web.config file:

```
    <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
     <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="IP Hit" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="54.163.166.178" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.shopindeal.in/{R:1}"redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>  
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

### A (HOST)

@ --> 54.163.166.178

### CNAME (Alias)

www --> @

and also did in

```
- <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
       <customErrors mode="Off"/> </system.web>
```

after deployed on aws it gives error

**500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.**

Is there anything else that I'm missing? I'm not sure why this isn't working.